# Masking a part of a page for basic users in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authorization, administration

I'll show you some screenshots, it will be easier to explain.

This is what I have :
http://www.noelshack.com/2012-23-1339063050-SiteWebV3.png 
With my "root" account, I can access to the entire page.

This is what I'd like to have :
http://www.noelshack.com/2012-23-1339063050-SiteWebV3LimitedAccess.png 
I want to limit access to users that are not root.

I know how to disallow access to the entire page, but I don't know ( if it's possible ) how to mask a part of my page.

I looked at this [page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871) but it didn't help me for what I want to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make two `WebUserControls` and can load them conditionally based on the type of user in the parent Page_Load Event or optionally you can make one usercontrol and set user specific controls visibility to read-only/visible=false by just exposing a Public Property of that `UserControl` and set it on the Page_load event based on the `UserType`

Comment: I don't know how usercontrols work because the default visual studio project already had one, but I found a tutorial so I'll try doing so. Thanks !

Thanks for the precisions in your edit, I'll try to do it :)

Comment: you are always welcome dear hope it helps

Comment: It sure will ! Post it as an answer if you want so I can rate it up and accept it as answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make two `WebUserControls` and can load them conditionally based on the type of user in the parent Page_Load Event or optionally you can make one `WebUserControl` and set user specific controls visibility to read-only/visible=false by just exposing a Public Property of that `UserControl` and set it on the `Page_load` event based on the `UserType`.

You can do it something like this also

```
    <% if (this.UserType== "root") { %>
    Loading user control with root user options
    <CTRL:A runat="server" />
<% } else { %>
    Loading user control with Non root User rights
    <CTRL:A runat="server" />
<% } %>
```

Hope it helps you in anyway

Comment: please don't hesitate to Unmark the answer if it doesn't work but it should i dont have any example to show you at this time and not having time to make one for you :) .

Comment: Don't worry about it, your answer is great, especially with the piece of code. It will help me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier ( the easiest ? ) way to do it if someone's interested :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Name) == "root")
            {
              //Your code if you're root
            }
            else
            {
             //Your code if you aren't
            }
   }
```

Of course you can change "Root" by your admin's username, or add many logins like this :

```
if (Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Name) == "root" || Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Name) == "AnotherLogin" || Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Name) == "Etc")
{
  //Blah blah
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yep, but I wouldn't have found it without your help :)

Comment: thanks but you yourself worked hard and got it working :) i dont deserve the credits now lolz you can optionally unmark my answer and mark your own if that really worked in your case

Comment: My solution worked too, but since I wouldn't have found it without you, you deserve it, don't be so modest ! :P